# Classify infinities

Tags: limits, infinity

In mathematics, "$\infty - \infty$" is an indetermination because $\infty$ can be reached by lots of different ways, and we can define some of them as "bigger" than the others. Counter-intuitively, we also have that $\infty = \infty + \infty = \infty^2 = e^\infty = \infty^\infty$. What a mess !

**Is there a way to "classify" the different infinities, in order to apply classical algebra to infinities ?** Is there some kind of "infinity-algebra" ? For instance, can we define:

$$\infty_0 := \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} x$$

We could consider that "$x\rightarrow +\infty$" $ \Leftrightarrow  $"$x\rightarrow \infty_0$", and thus:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty_0} x^2 = \infty_0^2$$

We would also have:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty_0} x = \infty_0 =\ "\frac{1}{0}"$$

and so on.

Comment: This is what the big O family of notations are for: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Big_O_notation
(It doesn't look anything like what you've written because that would be completely unworkable, but it captures the essential idea of comparing how quickly functions grow.)

Comment: This is perhaps peripheral to your actual question, but I would not say that $\infty-\infty$ is indeterminate: rather, it is simply undefined when working in the extended real number system, say. On the other hand, a *limit* of the form $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)-g(x)$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both approach $\infty$ as $x$ approaches $a$, is indeterminate. This means that the function $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $\phi(x,y)=x-y$ cannot be continuously extended to the point $(\infty,\infty)$, which is one reason why it is more convenient to leave $\infty-\infty$ as undefined.

Comment: To add to what @Joe wrote, $\infty-\infty$ is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). It does not necessarily mean its value cannot be determined, just that the technique that produced this indeterminate form is insufficient to determine the actual value. If you tried to evaluate $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))$ by splitting it into two limits, and got that indeterminate form, then splitting it was the wrong thing to do. The limit may well still exist anyway but it can only be determined by treating $f(x)-g(x)$ as a single whole.

Comment: There is a sort of "infinity algebra", although you might not like it. It's called "ordinal arithmetic", you can do a search for it. There is also Conway's construction of "surreal numbers", another concept you can search for.

Comment: "What a mess !" Exactly. This is the reason why $\infty$ cannot be trated as a number and there is no merit to try to make it a number with whatever exotic method.

Comment: [Another option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number).

Comment: @J.G. Exactly what I was thinking. The hyperreals form an ordered field that includes both infinite and infinitesimal numbers as well as all of the real numbers. Since they form a field, they satisfy all of the algebraic properties that the real numbers do (in fact, any property of the real numbers that can be expressed within first-order logic is also satisfied by the hyperreals. This is known as the transfer principle.) It is not trivial to develop though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For instance, can we define: $\infty_0 := \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} x$

Yes. Kind of. Such "limit" is called "germ". So what you propose is the germ of function $f(x)=x$ at infinity.

This kind of algebras is called [Hardy fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_field). Other approaches to this are formal power series and divergent integrals (your example would be represented as $\int_0^\infty dx$).

In the theory of divergent integrals or the theory of hyperfunctions (see Urs Graf) one can show that $\int_0^\infty dx=\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^2} dx$, thus indeed the "germ" of function $f(x)=x$ at infinity in a sense is equal to the germ of $g(x)=1/x$ at zero (from positive direction).

Following [Urs Graf's "Introduction to Hyperfunctions and Their Integral Transforms"](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=KHnABAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&source=gbs_book_other_versions), page 36:

[image]

If we insert here $x=0$, we will get $-i\pi\delta(0)$, which is the "value" of $\frac1{i0}$, multiplying the both sides by $i$ we get $1/{0^+}=\pi\delta(0)$, which is equal to the half of Fourier transform of $f(x)=1$ (which is $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }f(x)e^{-i\nu x}\,dx=2\pi\delta(\nu)$) evaluated at $\nu=0$, that is, $\int_0^\infty1dx=\pi\delta(0)=\frac{1}{0^+}$

Notice though that we cannot ascribe this value to $1/0$ because the function $1/x$ has germs at zero of opposite signs from the positive and negative directions.

The constant which you denote as $\infty_0$ is usually denoted as $\omega$ or $\varepsilon^{-1}$ (for instance, in Levi-Civita field, which is a kind of formal power series).