# What is truly infinity?

Tags: limits, infinity

I have seen arguments such as this
$\infty .0 = 0  $ or $\infty .0 = \infty$ and I have seen people disregard this kind of operation by saying that infinity is a concept and not a number so its illogical to perform operations with it. But we use infinity in so much other limits cases in physics and mathematics.

Like is the notion of saying $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) $$
What is the meaning of infinity here? If that x approaches an arbitrarily large number we can always imagine a number greater than that.

What does infinity really signify and why do we in some cases not agree with using infinity and what does it exactly mean by a number approaching infinity ?

Comment: Well, from what I know, yes! Infinity is a concept. $x\to\infty$ means the larger $x$ is (closer to $\infty$), the closer $f(x)$ will be to some value.

Comment: how do we know which value $\infty$ takes  ? Any number x approaches there are several numbers greater than that @TheMather-orratherAMather

Comment: Pretty sure $\infty$ doesn't have a given value... Yes, there are always numbers greater than a finite number, but take something like $dx\to0$. We know $0$ is finite, but $0.01$ is smaller than $0.1$. So is $0.001$, $0.000000001$, and you can go on forever... Hope that's correct :)

Comment: That limit has a definition.  To say that the limit is $L$ means that, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a value $N=N(\epsilon)$ such that $x>N\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.   We don't actually need to define the symbol "$\infty$" to define the limit.

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather yes , if its $0$ we know which value x approaches but if its $\infty$ we  dont know the value is what im trying to tell

Comment: @NaveenV well, I think it's more of an understanding... For $dx\to0$, not even $10^{-1000000}$ is the limit because we can keep going. Similarly, not even some **absurd** number like $10^{100000}!$ is the limit for $x\to\infty$. It just shows that the larger $x$ is, the closer $f(x)$ is to a value. I suppose $\infty$ is used to give that concept more "understandable", but this might be wrong 

Comment: The the symbol “$\infty$” describes a number that is definitely positive and indefinitely large. Representing all numbers that fall under this category with the same symbol is convenient and brings the appearance of closure to the set representation of the real  numbers.

Comment: The sense of “large” is a sense of (practical) perspective and has to do with the scale of measurement leading to the limitations of fully representing a (rational) number.

Adding any number to another number has meaning as long as the smaller number has a representation in the result. Otherwise the result could be approximated and represented as the larger number only.

Comment: Evaluating the limit of an expression (when possible) is akin to approximating the result. The expression will never be equal to its limit because the independent variable (usually x) never actually reaches its limit either. What the limit says in a case like this is that for independent variable indistinguishable close to its limit, the result of evaluation is also indistinguishable close to its limit (in your example, $x\approx x_0\Rightarrow f(x)\approx \lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)$).

Comment: In conclusion, evaluating a limit does not produce an exact answer but it produces an answer as close as needed to an exact representation of the answer.

Comment: Sometimes the expression that needs to be evaluated at limit appears in factor form: $a\times b$.

Comment: In such a case, if the factor a decreases to zero at a rate that appears accelerated compared to the rate at which the factor b increases, the prevailing rate of change for the entire expression is the accelerated decrease to zero. The result increases by a factor b and decreases way faster by a factor a. That’s why the result is as close as possible to zero which can be represented at limit as zero.

Comment: Possibly, this is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556508/classify-infinities/4556566#4556566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most ordinary math you have that the operations of addition and multiplication are defined for the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ or complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. Since$\infty$ is not a real number it isn't immediate how you would extend the definitions of addition and multiplication to include $\infty$. You can in a way consider the set $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ and extend the operations. In certain cases we do actually do this. One of them is measure theory we consider the non negative reals with infinity $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\cup \{\infty\}$ or $[0,\infty]$. In this context it makes sense to extend addition such that for all $x$ that $x+\infty=x+\infty=\infty$. You lose some algebraic properties when you do this, for example you can no longer have subtraction being well defined. You also have that the complex numbers with infinity form the so called Riemann Sphere on which for example all polynomial function extend naturally on.

Secondly there are certain "infinite" numbers such as cardinal numbers and ordinal numbers or hyperreal numbers for which the operations of addition and multiplication are well defined. These contexts are a bit different since you have many infinite numbers. So in no way is it illogical to have operations involving infinity. I would be better to say that their definition heavily depends on the context in which you are working in and in most cases are not defined.\

For the second part of your question is less algebraic and more topological. An "infinite" element may be added to a topological space to formalize the definition of a sequence "escaping" the space or becoming arbitrarily large. For example we have that the set $[0,+\infty]$ has a natural topology which makes it homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. A sequence of positive reals $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ becomes definitely arbitrarily large or rather: for all $M$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n> N$ we have $r_n>M$ if an only if the sequence $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $+\infty$ in the space $[0,+\infty]$. Similarly we have that a sequence on the Riemann sphere converges to $\infty$ if the modulus of the sequence becomes definitely arbitrarily large. 

To summarize, $\infty$ is usually used for convenience and its use varies from context to context. Many times it is used in hand wavy arguments or to help give some intuition as to what is happening. One last example is that if we have a sequence $(r_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} r_n=+\infty$ and another sequence such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} t_n=t$ where $t$ is a real number then we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} r_n+t_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} r_n+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} r_n=+\infty+t=\infty$. This gives a better picture of what is occuring then simply using limit definitions and is why sometimes a more hand wavy argument gives us better insight as to what is happening.